# Ng-options using filter stopped working to update angular

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework

I use this code with a select filtering options, which stopped working to update angular:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="datos.idEquipoSeleccionado"
ng-options="equipo.id_equipo as equipo.equipo for equipo in
datos.equiposFiltrados = (datos.equipos | filter: datos.buscar)"
ng-change="cambiaEquipo(datos.idEquipoSeleccionado)" >
</select>
```

JS:

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.datos = {
equipos: {},
equiposFiltrados: {},
idEquipoSeleccionado: 0,
buscar: '',
}

                    RankingServ.cargarEquipos(controlador, divId).then(function (equipos) {
                        $scope.datos.equipos = equipos;

                        if (Config.SELECCION !== null) {
                            $.each(equipos, function(key, value){
                                if (value.equipo == Config.SELECCION) {
                                    $scope.datos.idEquipoSeleccionado = value.id_equipo;
                                    $scope.cambiaEquipo(value.id_equipo);

                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, function(error) {
                    });
}]);
```

The error showing the console is:

```
Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%7D
J/<@http://localhost/app/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:40:416
...
a@http://localhost/app/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:22:1078

<select class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="datos.idEquipoSeleccionado" ng-options="equipo.id_equipo as equipo.equipo for equipo in
                    datos.equiposFiltrados = (datos.equipos | filter: 'san')" ng-change="cambiaEquipo(datos.idEquipoSeleccionado)">
```

Any idea what would be the problem? or change what makes it work?
Thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

Your `datos.equipos` is an object, but should be an array to use filter.

> Filter must be used with an array so a subset of items can be returned.

And follow the link your error logs for you 
[docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray) ;)